# Is it possible to hide a parent component from child component in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, web, components, parent-child, parent

As shown in the Flowchart ([Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mnGA.png)), I want to hide the **Header component** if **Main component** renders the **Login component**. But if the **Main component** renders the **Home component**, I want to display the **Header component**.

This is App.js file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Header from 'Header'
import Main from 'Main'
import Footer from 'Footer'

function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is Main.js file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Home from './Home'
import Login from './Login'

function Main() {

  let user = true //Toggled by users

  return (
    
    <div>
      {
        user ? ( <Home /> ) : ( <Login /> )
      }
    </div>
  
  )
}

export default Main
```

Putting the Header Component in Home itself will not solve the problem as I have to add much more pages and adding a Header component in every page doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please have a look now

Answer (score 1):

That's a use case of [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper), here your `user` state should be in the scope of `Header` and `Main`.

Then just pass the `user` (`isLogged` in the example) to `Main`, via props or Context API.

```
function Main({ isLogged, toggleLogin }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleLogin}>toggle</button>
      {isLogged ? <>Home</> : <>Login</>}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [isLogged, toggle] = useReducer((p) => !p, false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!isLogged && <>Header</>}
      <Main isLogged={isLogged} toggleLogin={toggle} />
      <>Footer</>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Template (forked)]